# I am want to use Spring Data + Phonixdriver to perform SQL like operation on HBSE

Tags: jpa, spring-data, hbase

I can able to perform SQL using simple spring JDBCTemplate using Phonix driver.

Is there any way to use spring-Data-jpa to perform same operation.

Phonix driver help me for SQL operation on HBSE nosql database.

As per my understanding As long as I can perform SQL using JdbcTemplate I should able to use spring data too.

I am getting below error

> *org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested
>   service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1078)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120)
>   [spring-boot-test-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
>   [spring-test-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
>   [spring-test-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
>   [spring-test-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:189)
>   [spring-test-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:131)
>   [spring-test-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
>   [spring-test-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228) [spring-test-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
>   [spring-test-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]   at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>   [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
>   [spring-test-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
>   [spring-test-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
>   [spring-test-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>   [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>   [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>   [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>   [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>   [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
>   [spring-test-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
>   [spring-test-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>   [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
>   [spring-test-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]   at
>   org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
>   [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]     at
>   com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
>   [junit-rt.jar:na]     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
>   [junit-rt.jar:na]     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
>   [junit-rt.jar:na]     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
>   [junit-rt.jar:na] Caused by:
>   org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested
>   service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]   at
>   org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:264)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:228)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:207)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:207)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:847)
>   ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:874)
>   ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]  at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
>   ~[spring-orm-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353)
>   ~[spring-orm-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:370)
>   ~[spring-orm-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:359)
>   ~[spring-orm-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]     ... 39 common
>   frames omitted Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to
>   DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:100)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:54)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:137)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:254)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]   ... 55 common frames
>   omitted*

Comment: can you share the code snippet you are using for this ?

Comment: After lot of research there is no SpringData support for Phonix.